# Tic Tac Toe in the Console

Tags: c#, game, console, tic-tac-toe

I have made a Tic Tac Toe game in C#. How can I improve my code? The full listing is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace TicTacToe1
{
    class Program
    {
        private char winChar;
        public char winPerson
        {
            get
            {
                return winChar;
            }
            set
            {
                winChar = value;
            }
        }
        private bool hasWon;
        public bool isWin
        {
            get
            {
                return hasWon;
            }
            set
            {
                hasWon = value;
            }
        }
        private bool isX;
        public bool isY
        {
            get
            {
                return isX;
            }
            set
            {
                isX = value;
            }
        }
        private char boxone, boxtwo, boxthree, boxfour, boxfive, boxsix, boxseven, boxeight, boxnine;
        public char box1
        {
            get
            {
                return boxone;
            }
            set
            {
                boxone = value;
            }
        }
        public char box2
        {
            get
            {
                return boxtwo;
            }
            set
            {
                boxtwo = value;
            }
        }
        public char box3
        {
            get
            {
                return boxthree;
            }
            set
            {
                boxthree = value;
            }
        }
        public char box4
        {
            get
            {
                return boxfour;
            }
            set
            {
                boxfour = value;
            }
        }
        public char box5
        {
            get
            {
                return boxfive;
            }
            set
            {
                boxfive = value;
            }
        }
        public char box6
        {
            get
            {
                return boxsix;
            }
            set
            {
                boxsix = value;
            }
        }
        public char box7
        {
            get
            {
                return boxseven;
            }
            set
            {
                boxseven = value;
            }
        }
        public char box8
        {
            get
            {
                return boxeight;
            }
            set
            {
                boxeight = value;
            }
        }
        public char box9
        {
            get
            {
                return boxnine;
            }
            set
            {
                boxnine = value;
            }
        }
        public void WriteBoard()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" {0} | {1} | {2} ", boxone, boxtwo, boxthree);
            Console.WriteLine(" --------- ");
            Console.WriteLine(" {0} | {1} | {2} ", boxfour, boxfive, boxsix);
            Console.WriteLine(" --------- ");
            Console.WriteLine(" {0} | {1} | {2} ", boxseven, boxeight, boxnine);
        }
        public void CheckWin()
        { // 123, 456, 789, 147, 258, 369, 159, 357
            if ((box1 == 'X') && (box2 == 'X') && (box3 == 'X'))
            {
                isWin = true;
                winPerson = 'X';
                return;
            }
            if ((box4 == 'X') && (box5 == 'X') && (box6 == 'X'))
            {
                isWin = true;
                winPerson = 'X';
                return;
            }
            if ((box7 == 'X') && (box8 == 'X') && (box9 == 'X'))
            {
                isWin = true;
                winPerson = 'X';
                return;
            }
            if ((box1 == 'X') && (box4 == 'X') && (box7 == 'X'))
            {
                isWin = true;
                winPerson = 'X';
                return;
            }
            if ((box2 == 'X') && (box5 == 'X') && (box8 == 'X'))
            {
                isWin = true;
                winPerson = 'X';
                return;
            }
            if ((box3 == 'X') && (box6 == 'X') && (box9 == 'X'))
            {
                isWin = true;
                winPerson = 'X';
                return;
            } // 159, 357
            if ((box1 == 'X') && (box5 == 'X') && (box9 == 'X'))
            {
                isWin = true;
                winPerson = 'X';
                return;
            }
            if ((box3 == 'X') && (box5 == 'X') && (box7 == 'X'))
            {
                isWin = true;
                winPerson = 'X';
                return;
            }
            if ((box1 == 'Y') && (box2 == 'Y') && (box3 == 'Y'))
            {
                isWin = true;
                winPerson = 'Y';
                return;
            }
            if ((box4 == 'Y') && (box5 == 'Y') && (box6 == 'Y'))
            {
                isWin = true;
                winPerson = 'Y';
                return;
            }
            if ((box7 == 'Y') && (box8 == 'Y') && (box9 == 'Y'))
            {
                isWin = true;
                winPerson = 'Y';
                return;
            }
            if ((box1 == 'Y') && (box4 == 'Y') && (box7 == 'Y'))
            {
                isWin = true;
                winPerson = 'Y';
                return;
            }
            if ((box2 == 'Y') && (box5 == 'Y') && (box8 == 'Y'))
            {
                isWin = true;
                winPerson = 'Y';
                return;
            }
            if ((box3 == 'Y') && (box6 == 'Y') && (box9 == 'Y'))
            {
                isWin = true;
                winPerson = 'Y';
                return;
            } // 159, 357
            if ((box1 == 'Y') && (box5 == 'Y') && (box9 == 'Y'))
            {
                isWin = true;
                winPerson = 'Y';
                return;
            }
            if ((box3 == 'Y') && (box5 == 'Y') && (box7 == 'Y'))
            {
                isWin = true;
                winPerson = 'Y';
                return;
            }
        }
        public void NotVacantError()
        {
            _error = true;
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Error: box not vacant!");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to try again..");
            Console.ReadKey();
            return;
        }
        public void DisplayLoss()
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("No one won.");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }
        private bool hasError;
        public bool _error
        {
            get
            {
                return hasError;
            }
            set
            {
                hasError = value;
            }
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            int moveCount = 0; // check loss
            char askMove; // display X or Y in question
            int selTemp;
            TicTacToe1.Program prog = new TicTacToe1.Program();
            prog._error = false;
            prog.box1 = ' '; prog.box2 = ' '; prog.box3 = ' ';
            prog.box4 = ' '; prog.box5 = ' '; prog.box6 = ' ';
            prog.box7 = ' '; prog.box8 = ' '; prog.box9 = ' ';
            prog.isY = true;
            Console.WriteLine(" -- Tic Tac Toe -- ");
            Thread.Sleep(1200);
            Console.Clear();
            while (!prog.isWin)
            {
                if (moveCount == 9)
                {
                    prog.DisplayLoss();
                }
                if ((prog.isY) == true) // if is X
                {
                    askMove = 'X';
                }
                else
                {
                    askMove = 'Y';
                }
                Console.Clear();
                prog.WriteBoard();
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("What box do you want to place {0} in? (1-9)", askMove);
                Console.Write("> ");
                selTemp = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                switch (selTemp)
                {
                    case 1:
                        if (prog.box1 == ' ')
                        {
                            prog.box1 = askMove;
                            moveCount++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            prog.NotVacantError();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        if (prog.box2 == ' ')
                        {
                            prog.box2 = askMove;
                            moveCount++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            prog.NotVacantError();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        if (prog.box3 == ' ')
                        {
                            prog.box3 = askMove;
                            moveCount++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            prog.NotVacantError();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        if (prog.box4 == ' ')
                        {
                            prog.box4 = askMove;
                            moveCount++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            prog.NotVacantError();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        if (prog.box5 == ' ')
                        {
                            prog.box5 = askMove;
                            moveCount++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            prog.NotVacantError();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        if (prog.box6 == ' ')
                        {
                            prog.box6 = askMove;
                            moveCount++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            prog.NotVacantError();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        if (prog.box7 == ' ')
                        {
                            prog.box7 = askMove;
                            moveCount++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            prog.NotVacantError();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        if (prog.box8 == ' ')
                        {
                            prog.box8 = askMove;
                            moveCount++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            prog.NotVacantError();
                        }
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        if (prog.box9 == ' ')
                        {
                            prog.box9 = askMove;
                            moveCount++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            prog.NotVacantError();
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Wrong selection entered!");
                        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to try again..");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                        prog._error = true;
                        break;
                }
                if (prog._error)
                {
                    prog.CheckWin(); // if error, just check win
                    prog._error = !prog._error;
                }
                else
                {
                    prog.isY = !prog.isY; // flip boolean
                    prog.CheckWin();
                }
            }
            Console.Clear();
            prog.WriteBoard();
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("The winner is {0}!", prog.winPerson);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This doesn't make sense to me

> ```
>     private bool isX;
>     public bool isY
>     {
>         get
>         {
>             return isX;
>         }
>         set
>         {
>             isX = value;
>         }
>     }
> ```

Are you checking for `X` or `Y`  I assume you want 2 separate methods here or you just named these incorrectly.

Here is where that incorrectly named variable comes back to bite you

> ```
> if ((prog.isY) == true) // if is X
> {
>     askMove = 'X';
> }
> else
> {
>     askMove = 'Y';
> }
> ```

You had to write a comment here to explain what was going on, when it should be straight forward.

my suggestion is to change

```
private bool isX;
```

to

```
private bool _isX;
```

and then rewrite your public call like this

```
public bool isX
{
    get
    {
         return _isX;
    }
    set
    {
         _isX = value;
    }
}
```

or better yet, get rid of the private declaration and write the whole thing like this

```
public bool isX
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

---

your `main` method has a lot going on inside of it that you should probably give to other methods and just call them in the `main` method.

like

```
            if (moveCount == 9)
            {
                prog.DisplayLoss();
            }
```

could be it's own method called `CheckForStaleMate()`

and your `switch (selTemp)` could be inside a Method called `CheckMove()`

You could also create a method for your output as well.  There shouldn't be much in your `main` method, it should be clean and should only call methods or possibly create an object or two.

Answer (score 13):

Some quick remarks:

- public properties should be [PascalCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx).
- use [Auto-Implemented Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx).
- Capitalize the various parts of `boxone` etc., e.g. `boxOne`. Avoid using numbers in your names, e.g. `box9`.
- Do not start properties with an underscore: `public bool _error`.
- `CheckWin()` repeats the same code over and over again, surely it can be reduced to something far simpler by calling another method with some parameters.
- Same for `switch (selTemp)` in your `Main()`: surely that can be significantly reduced.
- If you have properties, why do you use the private fields and not the properties?
- Don't do this: `private char boxone, boxtwo, boxthree, boxfour, boxfive, boxsix, boxseven, boxeight, boxnine;`
- Is there even a need for the individual declaration of boxes? Wouldn't it be simpler to store the values of the nine positions in an array or a dictionary?

Answer (score 8):

Why not store moves as a string of 0s and 1s instead of 9 properties?  For instance this:

```
_ X _
_ X O
X O _
```

could be represented as:

```
string xmoves = "010010100"
string omoves = "000001010"
```

---

With this scheme, you can store all of the winning moves (there are only 8) in an array of strings:

```
string[] winningMoves = {
    "111000000",
    "000111000", ... }
```

---

Then to check if x wins, you have a simple algorithm like this:

```
static bool IsWin(string moves, string[] winningMoves)
{
    foreach (var item in winningMoves)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < item.Length; i++)
        {
            if (item[i] == '1' && moves[i] == '1')
            {
                count++;
                if (count == 3)
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

You'll need a function that checks if a move is possible.  This is easy:

```
static bool CanMove(int index, string xmoves, string ymoves)
{
    return xmoves[index] == '0' && ymoves[index] == '0';
}
```

---

Finally, to make a move, you need to do a little string concatenation:

```
static string Move(int index, string moves)
{
    return string.Format("{0}1{1}", moves.Substring(0, index), moves.Substring(index + 1));
}
```

---

I'd be tempted to store the moves in binary rather than a string so that I can utilize bit-level operations.  This would make the code uglier however.  For instance, CanMove would look like:

```
static bool CanMove(int index, int xmoves, int ymoves)
{
    int bit = 1 << index;
    return (xmoves & bit) == 0 && (ymoves & bit) == 0;
}
```

Which I find much less intuitive.

Comment: I honestly don't think this is a good way of structuring the moves. There is some constraints that needs to be applied on the strings. For example, they should only contain 0's and 1's - number 2 in a string would have no meaning. Additionally, a '1' must not occur in the same index in both strings. These things are telling me that a better structure would be a 2d array of an enum.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg, I agree that the programmer should be aware of these problems. Other problems involve the fact that I assume strings are nine chars long, or that I'm making an assumption about the indexing of the tic-tac-toe board.  If the programmer properly encapsulates my code, these problems won't be an issue.  I wanted to illustrate a more succinct solution to the OP. I might change the the CanMove() and Move() methods to one TryMove() method though.

Answer (score 5):

You should definitely think about renaming your identifiers. It is important that you are able to recognize the code on your own a few weeks later, so you should maybe look at things **like the Hungarian** notation, which are about prefixing the identifiers. The identifiers should also have definite names which are recognizable for you later on.

One possibility to avoid code like this

```
private bool isX;
public bool isY
{
    get
    {
        return isX;
    }
    set
    {
        isX = value;
    }
```

is to call `isX` `fbIsX` and calling the Property implementation of it `isX`.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Code Review! Your first answer looks good, you could also always improve answers by linking to relevant concepts, or further details (e.g. to Wikipedia on [Hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation)).

Comment: Thanks for the hint, i will keep it in mind for my next answer :)

Comment: Hungarian Notation isn't preferable to other naming schemes like the underscore before the private property name, ie (`private _isX` -> `public isX`).  what is `fb` supposed to stand for anyway?

Comment: Probably worth noting that hungarian notation is very non-standard in modern C# (except I guess for the conventional `I` at the beginning of interface names and `T` at the beginning of generic type parameter names)

Comment: @Malachi the fb is supposed to stand for field boolean

Comment: I definitely wouldn't have figured that out right away.  if you are going to use true Hungarian notation it would be `boolX` not `isX` or `fbIsX`.  I believe the prefixes are: int, str, bool, btn, etc.  you want to know right away from looking at the name what the field is, but `isX` tells me right away that it is a boolean, it's a "yes or no" question

Comment: I dont agree with that because isX could also be an object with multiple properties. As the projekt gets larger, you wont be able to differentiate. The main aspect of my answer should be to show ONE posiblity of prefixing because it is proved that they increase code readability if done right. There is also not "THE ULTIMATE PREFIX LIST" - every team has a developer guide which has rules for prefixing. Using the modifier and the first char of the type is just one way to go which I use a lot in my projects.

Comment: an object has a different naming standard. I would never name an object `isX` what is `isX`? if I were going to name a class it would be `IsX` and not `isX`  but I wouldn't even do that, because that doesn't tell me what it is.  Your "way to go" isn't standard. where has Hungarian Notation been proven more readable than standard C# naming schemes?

Comment: Just chiming in here... [Hungarian Notation itself isn't evil. It's just hard to do it ***right***](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Wrong.html). And @Malachi you're thinking of *Apps* hungarian, which is agreed by all to be a horrible idea.

Answer (score 1):

You don't do anything non-standard in your getters or setters. Instead of:

```
private char winChar;
public char winPerson
{
    get
    {
        return winChar;
    }
    set
    {
        winChar = value;
    }
}
```

Just do:

```
public char WinPerson { get; set; }
```

Much more readable and does exactly the same.

Public property names are by convention supposed to be PascalCase, so I called it `WinPerson` instead of `winPerson`.

Also, if for some reason you DO need those private fields declared explicitly, don't name them differently - just make them start with lower case or _. Like this:

```
private char _winPerson;
public char WinPerson
{
    get
    {
        // do some more things, so this kind of property is justified
        return _winPerson;
    }
    set
    {
        _winPerson= value;
    }
}
```